# Deserialize immutable classes with interface parameter in the constructor using json.net

Tags: c#, constructor, interface, json.net, immutability

I want to create some immutable classes with Json.net, but encountered error message: "Could not create an instance of type SolutionName.InterfaceClassName.Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated".

## The problem:

I have an immutable class with some interface implemented.

```
public interface ISubClass1
    {
        int number { get; }
        string string1 { get; }
    }
```

Subclass:

```
public class SubClass1 : ISubClass1
    {
        public int number { get; }
        public string string1 { get; }  

        public SubClass1(int a, string str1)
        {
            number = a;
            string1 = str1;
        }
    }

public class SubClass2 : ISubClass1
        {
            public int number { get; }
            public string string1 { get; }  
            public string string2 { get; }  

            public SubClass2(int a, string str1, string str2)
            {
                number = a;
                string1 = str1;
                string2 = str2;
            }
        }
```

Implementation:

```
class Class1
    {
        public int SomeInt{ get; }
        public ISubClass1 SomeInterface { get; }

        public Class1(int a, ISubClass1 subclass)
        {
            SomeInt= a;
            SomeInterface = subclass;
        }
    }
```

I can serialize this object, everything works. But an error will occur during deserialization

```
"Could not create an instance of type SolutionName.InterfaceClassName.Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated"
```

This is due to `ISubClass1 subclass` can not be recognized by Json.net.

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: @InBetween I could make this into Q&A format, please read the first paragraph, and is this how you treat people who share knowledge?

Comment: If you know the answer, why ask the question?

Comment: @InBetween Because I searched for a solution for 1 week, and there was none here. So I wanted to document this process to help others after I solved this issue?

Comment: Yes, your intention is very laudable but this site doesn't work this way. If there is no match in SO its either due to not searching well, its not a common issue or people generally know already how to solve it.

Comment: @Middle don't post the answer in the question. Answer your own question! And mark it as the correct answer. It's something valid.

Comment: @DrkDeveloper I can definitely do that.

Comment: @InBetween This assumption is very flawed. I am an example of someone seeking answer and couldn't get it, and I didn't have to waste a week's time if post like this is present.

Comment: Related or duplicate: [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182), [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182), [Private setters in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4066947/3744182), [Json.net `JsonConstructor` constructor parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43032552/3744182).

Comment: @dbc Related yes, please refer to solution step 3 for the answers not present in all the above posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The solution:

You will need custom Json converter so that you can resolve `ISubclass1` with the concrete types you desire.

1 - Add this generic converter to your solution.

```
    public abstract class JsonCreationConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Create an instance of objectType, based properties in the JSON object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="objectType">type of object expected</param>
        /// <param name="jObject">
        /// contents of JSON object that will be deserialized
        /// </param>
        protected abstract T Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject);
    
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }
    
        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
                                        Type objectType,
                                         object existingValue,
                                         JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // Load JObject from stream
            JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
    
            // Create target object based on JObject
            T target = Create(objectType, jObject);
    
            // Populate the object properties
            serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);
    
            return target;
        }
    }
```

2 - Then inherit any interface you want to translate like the example below. Take note that `FieldExists` check is checking for a field that would identify the type of subclass. This way Json do not need `$type` information in order to deserialize correctly.
Reference: [BulletProof Deserialization](https://skrift.io/issues/bulletproof-interface-deserialization-in-jsonnet/)

```
    public class SubClass1Converter : JsonCreationConverter<ISubClass1>
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Use default serialization.");
        }
    
        protected override ISubClass1 Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
        {
            if (FieldExists("string2", jObject))
            {
                return new SubClass2();
            }
            else
            {
                return new SubClass1();
            }
        }
    
        private bool FieldExists(string fieldName, JObject jObject)
        {
            return jObject[fieldName] != null;
        }
    }
```

3 - You have modify your subclasses and implementations with Json.net Attributes, else deserialization will default values to null. You have an immutable class with some interface implemented.

Some keys points:

1. `[JsonProperty]`  needs to be present on every property, else the properties will be read as null;
2. `[public SubClass1() { }]`  an empty constructor needs to be present for converters declare an empty class.
3. `[JsonConstructor] ' needs to be marked on the constructor that allow properties to get values passed to them in the immutable objects.
4. `{ get; }` needs to be changed to `{ get; private set; }` else all properties will set to null
5. `public ISubClass1 SomeInterface { get; private set;}` in the implementation needs to be marked with `[JsonConverter(typeof(SubClass1Converter))]` attribute.

Subclass:

```
    public class SubClass1 : ISubClass1
        {
            [JsonProperty] 
            public int number { get; private set;}
            [JsonProperty]
            public string string1 { get; private set;} 

            public SubClass1() { }

            [JsonConstructor]
            public SubClass1(int a, string str1)
            {
                number = a;
                string1 = str1;
            }
        }

    public class SubClass2 : ISubClass1
            {
                [JsonProperty] 
                public int number { get; private set;}
                [JsonProperty]
                public string string1 { get; private set;} 
                [JsonProperty]
                public string string2 { get; private set;}  

                public SubClass2() { }

                [JsonConstructor]
                public SubClass2(int a, string str1, string str2)
                {
                    number = a;
                    string1 = str1;
                    string2 = str2;
                }
            }
```

Implementation:

```
class Class1
    {
        [JsonProperty] 
        public int SomeInt{ get; private set;}
        [JsonProperty]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(SubClass1Converter))]
        public ISubClass1 SomeInterface { get; private set;}

        [JsonConstructor] 
        public Class1(int a, ISubClass1 subclass)
        {
            SomeInt= a;
            SomeInterface = subclass;
        }
    }
```

## Usage:

```
JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
jsonSettings.Converters.Add(new SubClass1Converter()); //Optional
jsonSettings.ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor; //Optional

string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cls1, jsonSettings);

Class1 deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(jsonStr , jsonSettings);
```

References:

- [Casting interfaces for deserialization in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780888/casting-interfaces-for-deserialization-in-json-net)
- [c# Json.net immutable class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202726/c-sharp-json-net-immutable-class)

Comment: Mark the answer as the correct, don't forget it.